# not able to understand @encode and objCType

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came across a code snippet:
`if(strcmp([obj objCType], @encode(BOOL))) == 0)` where `obj` is a kind of `NSNumber`.
What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break it up.

`[obj objCType]` returns a `char *` containing the Objective-C [encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) for that `NSValue`.

- `NSNumber` is a subclass of `NSValue`.

`@encode(BOOL)` does the same for the type `BOOL`.

`strcmp()` compares two string. If the string are equal it returns `0`.

`strcmp(…) == 0` returns true if `strcmp()` compared to equal strings.

---

I think you see where this is going: The condition returns true, if the NSValue `obj` has an encoding equal to the encoding of the type `BOOL`.